# A zombie apocalypse is happening, what is the worst measures that a government can take?

Tags: zombies

So a zombie apocalypse is happening in two stages.

First the "infection" is airborne and just popped all over the world
In this stage only 1 in 3 will start changing into a zombie. 
It also takes exactly 13 days for the thing to start. 
That means that by the first time documented case is made an the world starts taking notice, it's already too late as 1 in 3 is already a zombie.
Obviously that thing is made and not natural. 
It boils down to either you will get infected in the initial stage and turn, or you will get first degree immunity.

Edit: The time it takes for people to actually turn into zombies in this stage differs greatly, sorry for not making it clear.
So some can change immediately while others will more time. 
This is in opposition to the second stage where pretty much all the cases follow the 2-5 hours timetable.

The second stage happens when a sufficient number of people already turned into zombies. 
The airborne "virus" is gone. No new people are being infected this way. 
And those not originally infected are immune.
However a zombie bite can change that. And turns people without 2-5 hours.

Now I just want to limit the question to the broad practices that any government can take to make matters worse.

**So what is the worst actions that the government can do in containing the infection?**

**Like it's the reverse of: How can a government contain the zombie apocalypse. 
Only here they are doing it out of pure stupidity.**

Anyway if your require more information just ask.

Comment: Insist that the zombie problem isn't that bad, and hold voter rallies where anti-zombie measures are forbidden.

Comment: President: "Suppose we hit the body with a tremendous ultraviolet or just very powerful light." Then wink at a health authority. "The disinfectant knocks it out in a minute. One minute,” “Is there a way we can do something like that by injection inside?"

Comment: ***1 in 3???*** You mean by the time government figures out there's a problem 33% of the population is, not just infected, but *zombies?* Seallussus... A 33% reduction in government staffing over any period of time would cripple any nation. The confusion caused by it happening in just 2 weeks would be devestating. O.M.'s absolutely correct - your question's meaningless because no government can react with so much disruption and so little time. And by the end of those first 2 weeks everyone bitten changes in hours.... Your premise is impossible. (\*continued\*)

Comment: Look at what just happened with the Coronavirus ... and it infected (but did not result in debilitation but in a fraction of cases) ***only 0.1% of the population.*** It's resulted in massive unemployment, massive welfare, all kinds of problems.  Although I will give you a hint: the worst thing any government can do in any situation like this is *deny it.*

Comment: Listen to social media influencers arguing that anti-zombie measures are bigoted and living-normative.

Comment: Just ask what Trump would do and you got yourself an answer.

Comment: "your question's meaningless"
"Your premise is impossible"
I think you are misunderstanding the question.
The premise is simple. 
The infection will destroy civilization, it's made to do so by certain power.
It's never a matter of can we contain this or can we get back or can we cure it.
It's a matter of an intelligent made infection that is simply unmanageable by any nation or all of us combined.
That aside. If you agree on the premise, which should be a given, that leaves little, very little, for governments to do.
But they do not do that little. 
So what is that little?

Comment: You're defending a very poorly thought-out question. The infection ***has*** destroyed civilization. The conditions you've provided destroyed government and its ability to react long before you need an answer. What do you think is happening during those first two weeks? People (of which governments are made) are *panicking.* They're locking their doors and praying not to be next (we've *already seen this happen.*) My local government shut down during COVID-19 despite having access to all staffers - and you just removed 1/3 of them. You need to start listening to us rather than defending this.

Comment: BTW, I happened to stumble on your response.  Remember to use the @ symbol to tap others on the shoulder, like this: @seallussus. When you do that the user you're notifying will be notified the next time he/she looks at any SE website. (p.s., it only works for people who have previously posted comments and you can only tap one person per comment.)

Comment: 5 answers and no upvotes!  If you like it enough to answer or to comment, you like it enough to upvote.

Comment: @JBH, 
You keep insisting on forcing a different premise for my question to "make sense"
it's impossible or poorly thought out or whatever.
It's like saying that a demons invade the earth and kill all humanity is bad because hey no fair.
So let me be clear.
THE INFECTION HAS TO GO DOWN THE WAY I WROTE.
YOU LOSE 1 IN 3 PEOPLE.
THE GOVERNMENT CAN DO VERY LITTLE.
THAT IS THE PREMISE.
THE PREMISE IS COMPLETELY HOPELESS SCENARIO.
Now can we move on or do I need to change the premise of my story to what you think is right?
Now I keep insisting it's a reverse of what can the government...

Comment: @JBH,
It's the exact reverse of what can they do.
Anyway I just don't get it.
Because it's like saying someone is dying, they are dying with absolute certainty they are dying. 
So what type of strong pain killers can the doctors provide?
Only for people here to write:
OH. That's just wrong. You can't save them. Your question is wrong.
Yes. They are dying. I'm merely looking to ease their pain.
But they are dying!
That's poorly thought out.
And so on

Comment: @Willk
Did all of what you said.

Comment: @Seallussus, [Frame challenges are permitted on this site](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7097/40609). You may not like it, but sometimes it's important to realize your premise has a problem. If you can't change our premise, then you need to deal with the reality that there's nothing the government can do pro or con. Cheers.

Comment: @JBH,
It's just your say so.
Not really. They can decide to nuke the entire planet. 
Here is a big thing they can do.
So if you just can't figure out how to work the problem within the setting then don't declare it impossible to be solved.
And the solution is pure stupidity in the face of impossible odds not solve the infection.
Just to hammer the point.

Comment: @Seallussus see my response to your comment on my answer. Story-based questions ("what choices can my character make?") are off-topic on this site. Give the government enough time and we can deal with the government as a system. Remove all the time and all that's left are off-topic character choices.

Comment: @JBH,
There is stomach for finer points here it seems.
As a last ditch attempt to stop an asteroid a group of oil drillers are sent into the thing to destroy it by digging and rigging the asteroid with nukes.
That movie made more than half a billion dollars.
So can humans think of a solution no matter how much you think it makes sense or not?
Yep. 
They can always make it worse.
My nuke example is perfect for this.
Can we invert that?
I'm pretty sure if people bothered to read the thing they could have came with with solutions despite the premise. 
I honestly don't get it.

Comment: @Seallussus [worldbuilding.se] isn't going to bow to how you want to use the site. Sorry. You might try Reddit or Quora.

Comment: @JBH,
Much like how I can't teach people how to properly argue about a point.
I actually respect the rules and the idea.
But if it's too difficult to demonstrate my point about how this is X rather than Y, then maybe the problem lies in people's assumptions.
Though I'm sure you will just argue that 5 is more likely to be true than one.
And I would quote Kierkegaard and say the crowd is untruth

Answer (score 10):

As you describe it, there is simply nothing the government (or anyone else) can do.

- The first stage has global range, with possible exceptions like ships at sea, research stations in Antarctica, the ISS.
- Then you get a situation where one in three is a "walking, biting" zombie. All within a few days. There will be no time to develop tests, quarantine will be pointless because there will be zombies *within* any conceivable perimeter.
- You might have some surviving individual preppers in their bunkers, but only as long as their supplies hold out. Civilization is gone.

If you want to tell a story where government stupidity made a difference, you have to stretch the timeline. There must be warning signs to be ignored.

Comment: Goo points.
But stupidity can play a part.
Zombies are not super powerful and the initial stages leave enough humans to fight on their own. 2 in every 3.
A human with a knife can dispatch a zombie in their house easily.
Entire households will be left intact.
The military can send members into isolation and basically lock down all their bases and wait for the turning and murder until they are clean.
Same with units. Just group together and kill the infected. 
There is a lot that can be done.
The sensible thing I think is for people to be on lock down in small groups.

Comment: @Seallussus, 2-in-3 is not enough to fight unless there is much more warning time. An **untrained** human with a knife might get bitten while trying to fight a zombie. Consider dog attacks on humans. So the zombie is dead and a few hours later there is a new one. And within the household the zombie would be a relative. You go to bed, the next morning your partner wakes up and tries to bite you. Do you use lethal force at once? The military would isolate units and then there would be infighting in the isolation areas. They are not prepared to send everyone into his own, defensible shelter.

Comment: I agree. But the premise, which is not completely set in stone, is that it's messed up and difficult but not impossible for people to do it.
You can chain people.
You can just sleep with a knife.
You can lock down your room...etc.
The military can also do something similar.
spreed your numbers and your soldier are already armed. 
And like I said after the initial stage there is no more danger from turning.
If you believe that your family member is a potential zombie then give it time and either you survive or don't. 
Problem solved.

Comment: @Seallussus, the timeframe is too short and the numbers are too high. Do you know the Latin term "decimatio"? Killing one in ten in a military unit would wreck it. Here you are talking about one in three, in a civilian society, and the victims can strike back and inflect the others.

Comment: Did not Crassus decimate a part of his army for fleeing, then that inspired them and the rest to actually fight and win against Spartacus?

Comment: You say you can lock people up and such but... how? As you've described it, there are no symptoms until they turn, so how could you possibly know who to lock up and who not?

Comment: @Cadence, 
You don't.
That's why you either quarantine people, if you can, or go around with a knife in your pocket.
The moment a family member starts changing you kill them.
And if you started changing they kill you.
Say you get a family of 4.
1 turns and he is killed without biting anyone.
That means that the others are probably immune.
You keep away for a while and if nothing happens then you are immune.
The only thing that will turn you then is a bite.

Comment: @Seallussus How does anyone know that? By the time anyone could possibly begin to start theorizing about this infection, the damage has already been done. And how do they know the rest of the family is immune in that case? They could still be vulnerable to a second-stage infection and it simply hasn't set in yet; you said yourself that the time it takes is variable.

Comment: @Cadence,
For them they won't get it that fast.
I just posted the rules for people to answer.
For the people they will have to figure out a way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 3):

You ever see *Doom Eternal*? Just do that. Downplay any concerns. Tell people that the infected are harmless, and people should be inviting the afflicted into their homes and caring for each other and coming together in this time of crisis. Ignore cries for help from cities asking for medical aid or military support to contain the infected. Outright lie to people that a zombie's bite isn't infectious. Maybe the politicians are doing this to buy time until they can evacuate to safe bunkers around the country. Maybe their brains have gotten so rotten by the virus their behavior is subverted *Cordyceps* or *Toxoplasma*-style and they are actually trying to spread the virus, enslaved to its whims. Basically keep people believing that nothing is wrong until it's too late, and then actively shame them when they try to take steps to protect themselves.

And given your description the government has good reason to try and downplay the danger to the public, as well. It's airborne, there's nothing the government can do to prevent or mitigate it, all they can do is try to prevent a panic. Especially if they might believe it could hurt their chances of being re-elected. As an aside, I could easily see a government IRL downplaying the severity of a disease to avoid a panic (look at what's happening now and the suggestions that have gone back and forth over which countries may or may not have misreported coronavirus numbers or downplayed its severity), it's hard to believe them going the "mortally challenged" route (which *would* be the absolute worst measures possible) without them being actively brainwashed by the disease. That's the point where you go from "depressingly realistic given politicians" to "too dumb to live".

Basically do the opposite of what governments around the world have done for covid: encourage people to go out and socialize rather than quarantine themselves.

Comment: I love your point about how if it's airborne they can do little.
So far they have to be incompetent and plain old stupid. 
Nothing to suggest the infection control.
Anyway good points.
I can see it.
Public announcement: Rumors of a so called zombie outbreak are completely unfounded and spread by ignorant and malicious media outlets.
Though as always remember to wash your hands to protect yourself from viruses, and enjoy your weekend in the sun and with family.

Comment: @Seallussus Can't take credit for the observation that if it's airborne they can do little. The comment by o.m. pointed that one out.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer explained why there is little a government can do, smart or stupid, to avert the apocalypse. But that is no constructive approach. So ...

Assume that there are *three* stages to the illness.

- The **first stage** is a highly contagious airborne virus, with immediate effects similar to a bad cold or a light flu. It gets detected by public health officials, there is a flurry of activity, then it becomes clear that the virus is "harmless." Within half a year, most humans are or "have been" infected.
- After a year in a human host, the **second stage** may or may not begin. Victims turn into stereotypical zombies with a hunger for human brains. There is no cure.

  - Roughly 10% transform between 12 and 24 months from the infection.
  - Roughly 10% transform between 2 and 10 years from the infection.
  - Roughly 10% transform later than 10 years from the infection.
  - 70% do not transform at all. They can still be bitten.
- The bite of a **second-stage** turns a victim into a **third-stage** zombie. Also mindless, also hungry for brains, but unlike the second stage this is curable.

This scenario gives you plenty of for government mistakes to make it worse.

- Ineffective quarantines and shutdowns fail to contain the first stage, but they do economic damage and discredit scientists. The virus jumps every quarantine protocol, perhaps with the exception of the ISS ...
- Hastily developed tests produce large number of false positives or negatives. So when the second stage happens it will be unclear if this is a delayed result of the first stage or an entirely new effect.
- Twelve months from the initial outbreak, there are the first second-stage cases. First one or two per day ("ordinary murders"), then dozens per day ("copycat killers"), then hundreds per day ("this rightist/leftist/whatever violence will not be tolerated, send in the cops").
- At some point the scientific community agrees that the first and second stages are related. The search for a vaccine or cure is complicated by the difference between the second and third stages.
- The number of first stage survivors is too large to lock them all up as a precaution. Governments may try, based on inaccurate numbers. Death rates in quarantine camps skyrocket from ordinary sanitation and supply problems. Armed resistance, riots, civil war, fortress enclaves by "negatives" who shoot all strangers.

Comment: Thanks.
But I think you are thinking of: A containable zombie outbreak is happening and but government is making it worse.
The premise is: an uncontainable zombie outbreak is happening and the government i making it worse.

Comment: @Seallussus, I don't think my scenario is containable. Whenever they **think** a site is clear, one of the first-stage victims goes second-stange.

Answer (score 1):

This zombie epidemic is a bad situation.  But one can always make a bad situation worse.

**Forced evacuation to high population density camps.**

Left to their own devices, some citizens and governments might come up with methods to sort out the infected early and prevent infection.   The worst thing the government could do is round everyone up by force and relocate them to high population density camps.  Individuals who try to flee will be captured and those who fight the government will be killed.

I can imagine a government with rational reasons to do this; even a government trying to help.

But of course this would be terrible.  Persons rounded up would be taken to camps with the clothes on their back.  Or not even that  - maybe they are given paper scrub suits to decrease infection risk.    When someone goes zombie the infection will race like wildfire thru the camp and that will be that.  It is hard to fight zombies with nothing but paper scrub suits and the plastic spork that came with dinner.

Answer (score 0):

Um... The worst thing they can do is be racist. If they go "you guys would not be saved from the disease", they'd turn into zombies and increase the number of zombies. Like there is still something to do for smart people and a stupid government, but leaving infected people to die (with a cure) is the worst thing you can do.

And this gives rise to some moral debate and stuff like that your protagonist can use to seem morally right and good for society at the same time.

(A comment told me that that is elitism (where a minority oppresses the majority). To be honest even if the minority is ignored it would probably still be a big issue, but yes, elitism is a more wide and proper definition.)

Comment: This isn't racism - it's elitism. Besides, racism (and most forms of bigotry) is always a function of the majority imposing its will on a minority. Using as an example Blacks in America, you're talking about turning away only 12% of the population. Elitism, on the other hand, would be something like the wealthy 1% turning away the rest of us. That would be a problem.

Comment: Ok... Perhaps that wasn't so clear. I'm editing it.

Answer (score 0):

**Frame Challenge**

IMO the worst thing any government can do is *nothing.* People aren't (generally) stupid and any action a government takes that would make the situation worse would be quickly rebelled against. Ignorance makes everything worse (as we just saw with the Coronavirus).

However, I contend that the OP's initial conditions guarantee *no government response of any kind (with the possible exception of a press release) is possible.*

**Statistics for the Obligatory Disease**

The *Pithovirus Sibericum*<sup>[1](https://www.pnas.org/content/111/11/4274),[2](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326871#3.-The-reanimated-virus)</sup> has mutated! Not only is it able to infect humans, it's airborne!

- The infection rate is a guaranteed 33%. Plonk an infected individual in a room with 100 people and 33 of them are instantly infected.
- The incubation period is 0-2 weeks. An infected individual is not infectious before the incubation period is complete. For the sake of analysis, the incubation period is linearly distributed across each infected group. So, 100 people result in 33 infections. 2 people turn into zombies immediately and 2 or 3 people change into zombies each day after that until all 33 are zombies by the end of day 14. There are 336 hours in 14 days so the infected group has a 1/336 or .298% chance of turning zombie each hour.
- To guarantee the greatest chance of a Zombie Apocalypse, we're starting the infection in Macao, China, which has the honor of being the most densely populated region in the world ([54,799 people per square mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population_density)). Macao's population in 2018 was 631,636. China's was 1.393 billion. The world's was 7.594 billion. Hold your breath.
- Worst-Case Assumption: the Earth's population density is equal to Macao's and the average zombie, who needs no rest nor sleep, can cover a square mile inside of an hour. Also assume every zombie moves on to better hunting grounds (maximum coverage). Rivers, oceans, and mountains are ignored (if you're thinking, "that's one spherical horse, JBH..." you're right on the money).

```
Hour     Zombies        Infected
--------------------------------------------------
Hour 1   1              18,266
Hour 2   55             1,022,860 Macao is 100% infected
Hour 3   3,099          57,627,183
Hour 4   174,608        3,246,903,605 China 100% infected (so is India)
Hour 5   9,838,012      182,941,646,730 the World is 100% infected (40 minutes ago...)
```

That's five hours, not two weeks, and nothing any government can do can make it worse: the worst has already happened. Two weeks later everybody's a zombie (phase II never takes place).

OK, that was worst-case. Now let's assume the population density of Zimbabwe (100 people per square mile) and also assume everyone's easily encountered at that rate. For fun (and convenience) we'll use Macao and China as our references again.

```
Hour     Zombies         Infected
--------------------------------------------------
Hour 1   1               33
Hour 2   1               66
Hour 3   1               99
Hour 4   1               132
Hour 5   1               165
Hour 6   1               198
Hour 7   2               264
Hour 8   3               363
Hour 9   4               495
Hour 10  5               661
Hour 11  7               892
Hour 12  10              1,222
Hour 13  14              1,685
Hour 14  19              2,313
Hour 15  26              3,173
Hour 16  35              4,331
Hour 17  48              5,918
Hour 18  66              8,100
Hour 19  90              11,076
Hour 20  123             15,143
Hour 21  168             20,698
Hour 22  230             28,303
Hour 23  314             38,686
Hour 24  429             52,871
Hour 25  586             72,247
Hour 26  801             98,732
Hour 27  1,095           134,938
Hour 28  1,497           184,436
Hour 29  2,046           252,087
Hour 30  2,796           344,537
Hour 31  3,821           470,879
Hour 32  5,222           643,545 Macao is 100% infected
Hour 33  7,137           879,530
Hour 34  9,755           1,202,079
Hour 35  13,333          1,642,934
Hour 36  18,223          2,2454,77
Hour 37  24,906          3,068,994
Hour 38  34,040          4,194,527
Hour 39  46,524          5,732,843
Hour 40  63,586          7,835,314
Hour 41  86,905          10,708,828
Hour 42  118,777         14,636,189
Hour 43  162,337         20,003,862
Hour 44  221,872         27,340,060
Hour 45  303,241         37,366,724
Hour 46  414,451         51,070,547
Hour 47  566,447         69,800,118
Hour 48  774,185         95,398,547
Hour 49  1,058,109        130,384,923
Hour 50  1,446,159        178,202,173
Hour 51  1,976,523        243,555,909
Hour 52  2,701,392        332,877,440
Hour 53  3,692,099        454,956,700
Hour 54  5,046,137        621,807,229
Hour 55  6,896,754        849,848,412
Hour 56  9,426,065        1,161,521,268
Hour 57  12,882,974       1,587,496,826 China is 100% infected
Hour 58  17,607,667       2,169,694,366
Hour 59  24,065,091       2,965,406,642
Hour 60  32,890,706       4,052,937,894
Hour 61  44,953,021       5,539,309,612
Hour 62  61,439,062       7,570,792,304
Hour 63  83,971,182       10,347,299,584 World is 100% infected (nearly an hour ago)
```

That's just over 2.5 days, not two weeks, and the problem is over. My contention is that under the present conditions imposed by the OP there is no way on the face of the Earth that any government could act in any way that could affect the spread of rampant zombieism in any way — good or bad.

- With rare exception, governments are always located in high-density population centers (even local governments claim this dubious honor, just on a smaller scale). Government, therefore, is the fist thing to go. Raw materials (farming/ranching, lumber, mining, etc.) would likely be the last.
- Panic would set in *incredibly quickly* with half-nonsense Twitter and Facebook posts coming out of infected areas and then suddenly (even for today's instantaneous communication) the posts would stop. The Internet would be consumed with fear, panic, and disinformation in less than 24 hours. (We saw this with the Coronavirus. I can't tell you how many "my friend's a nurse!" posts I saw being shared with useless information because nurses were posting fast without oversight or thought — and that's assuming all of them were nurses....)
- The reaction rate of government isn't predicted by the number of the infected, but by the number of zombies. However, the "it matters what the government does" period is predicted by the infection rate. In the worst-case scenario it's irrelevant. Governments can't even be predictably informed in just 5 hours, much less come up with a reaction. By the time the government made a decision to do anything the world is already 100% infected.
- In the best-case scenario you might actually see the government take an action — but I've never actually seen the United States government react in any meaningful way in just two days for any disaster in the past. Even Hurricane Katrina required, what, at least a week to start getting bottled water to people? And in 2.5 days it's all over.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I doubt a government could get a coherent press release out in just two and a half days.  Heck, let's double it (5 days). I still don't believe there's anything the government can do to make that worse ("worse" being defined as, "speed up the infection rate.")

I therefore contend that the OP's question isn't useful or well researched. I've down voted it for that reason. While answers to the question, "what could a government do to make the progress of a plague worse?" may be useful to the OP — none of them will be believable (even with suspension of disbelief) in his/her scenario.

## However

It may be that the OP's ambiguity meant that at the end of two weeks, 33% of the world's population was *infected* (whether or not they had turned into zombies doesn't matter). Let's look at it from this perspective. By day 14 the number of infected is only 2.531 billion. We'll use a pull-it-out-of-my-hat estimate of an average population density of 500/sqmi. To get there I had to reduce the infection rate from 33% to 0.3096%. But, how long until it's too late?

**353 hours: 14.7083 days.**

Yup, just 17 hours later it's all over.

I still contend that there's nothing a government can do to actually make the situation worse. There's simply not enough time for any government to react meaningfully.

During the Coronavirus (total infection as of 6/14/2020: 0.1% of the world's population) it took the government *months* to issue stay-at-home orders.  Granted, a fast-moving zombie apocalypse might move things along faster — but I continue to contend there would be so much panic and disinformation that it wouldn't matter.

*For the situation of a government acting to make a zombie apocalypse worse, the apocalypse would need a year or more to get to 33% infection.*

And for comparison, the Spanish Flu pandemic of 1918-1919 infected an estimated 33% of the world's population. I recommend the OP model his/her reactions against that timeline. At least one year.

*One last point: Government is being affected by the infection, too. And that affect is to reduce government efficiency, making it even slower to react. As panic sets in, people are staying home unless being forced to work. As people become zombies, they're not available to work. With each passing day there are fewer people the government can call on to make anything happen. According to that last simulation, when 33% of the world is infected, you also have 109 million zombies running around. That's 1.4% of the government that can't even be forced to work. It doesn't sound like much, but it underscores the problem.*

If the OP modifies his/her question to propose a scenario that's realistic, I'll gladly delete this post.

Comment: That's a pretty good replay.
But what makes you think I'm actually looking for 
"what could a government do to make the progress of a plague worse"
That matters?
Basically. You and your children are dying, what words of comfort can you provide?
Not how can you save your children. NOT THAT!
Like "These final hours" or "Seeking a Friend for the End of the World"
Or other ideas where certainty of doom is a given.
And I never claimed, or thought, that the government can contain or deal with it.
Civilization will collapse.
Was hoping for an idea about how stupid people might react.

Comment: Quote, **"what is the worst actions that the government can do in containing the infection?"** That's why I thought you were looking for "what could a government do to make the progress of a plague worse?" because, frankly, the worst thing they can do is anything that would make the progress work. You even said, **"How can a government contain the zombie apocalypse. Only here they are doing it out of pure stupidity,** which is a new but similar question. You didn't ask "what stupid human behavior can I expect when people realize there's no hope?" Please choose to be responsible for your post.

Comment: I suppose I should have made it more clear that the situation is hopeless and I'm looking for what people will still do.
Guess it all boils down to asking 2+2= what?

Comment: @Seallussus unfortunately, asking what people will do is off-topic here. We focus on the rules and systems of your world, not plot or characterization. Choices and even choice options are story-based because you can place whatever conditions you wish to get whatever choices you want.

Comment: Again jumping into conclusion.
I said invert the most logical response.
Where is the plot or characterization here?
Did I mention a single character?